# how to encode list of items and specify the order

Tags: encoding, compression, binary-data, huffman-code

I'm not sure of the best way to ask this, so let me start off with an example.

Lets say i have a complete list of possible items (i1, i2, i3, i4, .... i128). What i want is to specify a sub list (We'll call it list A) which specifies which items are in the list, and what the order of the list is. Now lets say i want to encode this in a way that it is a small as possible. Lets say List A is below:

```
i1, i2, i5, i20, i50, i80, i103, i121
```

if I know my items are always going to be sequential order, then i think i could easily just make a bit array, where a 1 would indicate the item is present, and a 0 indicating it's not. In my example i have 128 possible items, so i could represent what is present in 16 bytes. So list A would be

```
1100100000000000000100.......
In Bytes: C8 00 10 00 00 00 40 00 .....
```

but now, how can i express the order in such a way that i'm not using 8 more bytes?

I realize for this example, it would be less data to just encode the list in order by assigning each item to a specific value, and then putting those values whatever order i want them, but if my list is larger than 16 items, then i would start using more data in order to encode them.

is there a better way of going about this that i'm not thinking of? I hope what i've said makes sense. Please let me know if i can clarify anything and thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode the permutation as a [factoradic integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system). You will need big number routines for many items. It would require 90 bytes in the worst case, where you have a permutation of 128 items. Note that it would take 112 bytes to simply store the sequence using 7 bits per item.

In the case shown with only eight items, then two bytes are needed to code the permutation. Though with your 16 bytes with the bit map, you have 18 bytes total. As opposed to just seven bytes coding the values directly.

Overall, you're not going to see a whole lot of gain from the fact that your sequences are limited to non-repeating values.

Comment: Lets say i had some predefined lists that were known, say List B is all the even items, List C is all the add items, list D is just 1-8, etc. lets say i have something like 64 or 128 predefined lists. would there be a way that i could use these in order to reduce the data like this? I was thinking i might already have some or all of the items and their order stored already in parts of different predefined lists.Would there be an even better way of reducing this data by predefining something else? Thanks for your quick feedback!

Comment: Well, obviously if you have 128 pre-defined lists, then you can store an identifier for them in 7 bits.

Comment: Sure, but lets say i want to make a list that isn't in on of the predefined lists. Is there a way encode parts of multiple lists? For examples lets say i have list B as all the even items, and list E as items 1-20, and i wanted to make a new list that is [2, 4, 6, 8, 9-15, 16, 18, 20]. Would there be a way to uses lists B and E to define my new list? obviously this is a simple example, so my real question is can I use information from my pre-defined lists in order to define any new lists, while still only using small amounts of data. Thanks!

Comment: Unless you know something more about your data that either dramatically restricts the sequences that are possible (i.e. each time you eliminate half of the possible remaining sequences, you reduce the size of the representation by one bit), or dramatically skews the probabilities of seeing some sequences vs. others, then there is no escaping the number of bits required to represent all possible sequences with equal probability.  No matter how clever a scheme you try to create. (In fact, the more clever, the more bits you will use up as compared to a simple counting scheme.)

Comment: gotcha. I think that makes sense. Thanks a bunch for all your feedback!